# Doctrine creates table, but doesn't drop it

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

When I create tables for my entities, Doctrine creates `auth."user"` table no  problem:

```
[vagrant@localhost thiriscart]$ ./bin/console doctrine:schema:update --force --dump-sql
CREATE SCHEMA auth;
CREATE SCHEMA catalog;
CREATE SEQUENCE auth.user_id_seq INCREMENT BY 1 MINVALUE 1 START 1;
CREATE SEQUENCE catalog.category_id_seq INCREMENT BY 1 MINVALUE 1 START 1;
CREATE SEQUENCE catalog.product_id_seq INCREMENT BY 1 MINVALUE 1 START 1;
CREATE TABLE auth."user" (id INT NOT NULL, username VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY(id));
CREATE TABLE catalog.category (id INT NOT NULL, parent_id INT DEFAULT NULL, created_by INT NOT NULL, updated_by INT NOT NULL, title VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, description TEXT NOT NULL, slug VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, lft INT NOT NULL, rgt INT NOT NULL, root INT DEFAULT NULL, lvl INT NOT NULL, created_at TIMESTAMP(0) WITHOUT TIME ZONE NOT NULL, updated_at TIMESTAMP(0) WITHOUT TIME ZONE NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY(id));
CREATE INDEX IDX_D3431049727ACA70 ON catalog.category (parent_id);
CREATE INDEX IDX_D3431049DE12AB56 ON catalog.category (created_by);
CREATE INDEX IDX_D343104916FE72E1 ON catalog.category (updated_by);
CREATE TABLE catalog.product (id INT NOT NULL, main_category INT NOT NULL, title VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, digest TEXT NOT NULL, description TEXT NOT NULL, base_price NUMERIC(10, 2) NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY(id));
CREATE INDEX IDX_BC02688FDF6E08B4 ON catalog.product (main_category);
ALTER TABLE catalog.category ADD CONSTRAINT FK_D3431049727ACA70 FOREIGN KEY (parent_id) REFERENCES catalog.category (id) ON DELETE CASCADE NOT DEFERRABLE INITIALLY IMMEDIATE;
ALTER TABLE catalog.category ADD CONSTRAINT FK_D3431049DE12AB56 FOREIGN KEY (created_by) REFERENCES auth."user" (id) NOT DEFERRABLE INITIALLY IMMEDIATE;
ALTER TABLE catalog.category ADD CONSTRAINT FK_D343104916FE72E1 FOREIGN KEY (updated_by) REFERENCES auth."user" (id) NOT DEFERRABLE INITIALLY IMMEDIATE;
ALTER TABLE catalog.product ADD CONSTRAINT FK_BC02688FDF6E08B4 FOREIGN KEY (main_category) REFERENCES catalog.category (id) NOT DEFERRABLE INITIALLY IMMEDIATE;

Updating database schema...
Database schema updated successfully! "16" queries were executed
```

But doesn't drop it:

```
[vagrant@localhost thiriscart]$ ./bin/console doctrine:schema:drop --force --dump-sql
ALTER TABLE catalog.category DROP CONSTRAINT fk_d3431049727aca70;
ALTER TABLE catalog.category DROP CONSTRAINT fk_d3431049de12ab56;
ALTER TABLE catalog.category DROP CONSTRAINT fk_d343104916fe72e1;
ALTER TABLE catalog.product DROP CONSTRAINT fk_bc02688fdf6e08b4;
DROP SEQUENCE auth.user_id_seq CASCADE;
DROP SEQUENCE catalog.category_id_seq CASCADE;
DROP SEQUENCE catalog.product_id_seq CASCADE;
DROP SEQUENCE ext_log_entries_id_seq CASCADE;
DROP SEQUENCE auth.user_id_seq CASCADE;
DROP SEQUENCE catalog.category_id_seq CASCADE;
DROP SEQUENCE catalog.product_id_seq CASCADE;
DROP SEQUENCE ext_translations_id_seq CASCADE;
DROP SEQUENCE ext_log_entries_id_seq CASCADE;
DROP TABLE ext_translations;
DROP TABLE ext_log_entries;
DROP TABLE catalog.category;
DROP TABLE catalog.product
```

Even with `--full-database` option the `DROP TABLE` statement is generated, but, apparently, not executed:

```
[vagrant@localhost thiriscart]$ ./bin/console doctrine:schema:drop --force --full-database --dump-sql
ALTER TABLE catalog.category DROP CONSTRAINT fk_d3431049727aca70;
ALTER TABLE catalog.category DROP CONSTRAINT fk_d3431049de12ab56;
ALTER TABLE catalog.category DROP CONSTRAINT fk_d343104916fe72e1;
ALTER TABLE catalog.product DROP CONSTRAINT fk_bc02688fdf6e08b4;
DROP SEQUENCE ext_log_entries_id_seq CASCADE;
DROP SEQUENCE ext_translations_id_seq CASCADE;
DROP SEQUENCE auth.user_id_seq CASCADE;
DROP SEQUENCE catalog.category_id_seq CASCADE;
DROP SEQUENCE catalog.product_id_seq CASCADE;
DROP TABLE ext_translations;
DROP TABLE ext_log_entries;
DROP TABLE auth."user";
DROP TABLE catalog.category;
DROP TABLE catalog.product
[vagrant@localhost thiriscart]$ ./bin/console doctrine:schema:update --force --dump-sql
CREATE TABLE auth."user" (id INT NOT NULL, username VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY(id));
ALTER TABLE catalog.category DROP CONSTRAINT FK_D3431049DE12AB56;
ALTER TABLE catalog.category DROP CONSTRAINT FK_D343104916FE72E1;
ALTER TABLE catalog.category ADD CONSTRAINT FK_D3431049DE12AB56 FOREIGN KEY (created_by) REFERENCES auth."user" (id) NOT DEFERRABLE INITIALLY IMMEDIATE;
ALTER TABLE catalog.category ADD CONSTRAINT FK_D343104916FE72E1 FOREIGN KEY (updated_by) REFERENCES auth."user" (id) NOT DEFERRABLE INITIALLY IMMEDIATE;

Updating database schema...



  [Doctrine\DBAL\Exception\TableExistsException]
  An exception occurred while executing 'CREATE TABLE auth."user" (id INT NOT NULL, username VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, PRIM
  ARY KEY(id))':
  SQLSTATE[42P07]: Duplicate table: 7 ERROR:  relation "user" already exists






  [Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\PDOException]
  SQLSTATE[42P07]: Duplicate table: 7 ERROR:  relation "user" already exists






  [PDOException]
  SQLSTATE[42P07]: Duplicate table: 7 ERROR:  relation "user" already exists



doctrine:schema:update [--complete] [--dump-sql] [-f|--force] [--em [EM]]
```

Comment: Do you routinely use both --force and --dump-sql at the same time?  I usually use one of the other but not both.

Comment: @Cerad Well, yes. Why not? They have different meaning for me. Dump means print SQL, force means execute SQL against the database. Why not to do that at the same time? :)

Comment: I thought SF/Doctrine would throw an exception when you use both. But my apps are still at 2.3 LTS, so maybe it’s allowed in later versions.

Comment: I suppose you could verify that the database user has drop table permissions.  And of course you might give it a try with just --force.  But it all seems very strange.

Comment: Do you use dump-sql to generate some sql file and store them before manual execution ? If it is the case, have a look on doctrine:migration. It could help you more efficiently. You can generate sql file, and modify them and have an historic.

Comment: @AlexandreT No, I'm currently creating database structure directly from entity table information. I will later move into migrations of course.

Comment: What is your database engine ? I ask it, because I saw a difference in the foreign to drop. Its name is in uppercase during creation and in lower case  in drop query. If your database is case sensitive, it didn't drop the foreign key, and so on it can drop the table user (because of the two links with category)

Comment: @AlexandreT I use PostgreSQL 9.4. I use underscore naming strategy and all names, provided in Annotations are lowercased. BTW, I'm using Doctrine 2.5 with Symfony 2.7. Package versioning seem to allow this without problems.

Comment: The `./bin/console doctrine:schema:drop --force --full-database --dump-sql` doesn't alter your database schema. It only prompts the sql query. 

Try to execute
`./bin/console doctrine:schema:drop --force --full-database`

and then connect to postgres server with console and launch these command :
`\dt`
The command will show us the tables which stay in database

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `doctrine:schema:update` with the `--complete` parameter to fully sync the database with your entities.

```
app/console doctrine:schema:update --force --complete
```

or

```
app/console doctrine:schema:update --dump-sql --complete
```

Comment: It doesn't help for this case, unfortunately.

Comment: Are you 100% sure? Please do *not* use `--dump-sql` with `--force`. Use exactly this command line: `app/console doctrine:schema:update --force --complete`.

Comment: Unfortunately, it doesn't work either. It attempts to create user table anyway...